# Can I change the default color of an Image Border?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am working on app that has a story in a from of string and an image, being formatted using html to show up in a webview. image is enlrageable  and when that image in the webview is tapped, just to show that image is tapped, an outline or border is created around the image and then image is enlarged.

now, i want to change that particular color which shows that, image is in tapped state. any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example. It is a good tip. [Change WebView Highlight Color](http://www.randomtools.net/how-to-hide-android-webview-highlight-border-or-change-its-color-142.html)

Comment: That was really a helping one..:-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a WebView - use HTML to style the border? Otherwise use a background drawable to set a border.

Comment: absolutely it is in web-view, but i am unable to understand how i'll use Html strings to create an event somewhat like onClick. As far as i understand it'll be done through JavaScript, but dont understand how to write JavaScript in html strings in Eclipse. tell me please, or if there is some other way to do it so. thanks.:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor RedColor] CGColor];
```